# Nextflow - Channel.watchPath() method

Tags: python, nextflow

I am trying to use nextflow to gain some concurrency from my python scripts so some of my dataflow doesn't use the traditional nextflow ideals.

In my first process I create files by invoking a python script, in my second process I want to use those files created

I created a new channel that watches for the path where the files are created but nothing seems to happen. I tested with the .fromPath method and my process is successful, so I am not sure whats going wrong?

```
mutFiles = Channel.watchPath(launchDir + '/output/mutFiles/*.mutfile')


process structurePrediction{

    input:
    file mutFiles

    output:
    stdout results


    """
    test.py ${mutFiles}
    """

}
```

Comment: Are you sure the files aren't created in the workdir of the process that creates the file? Instead of at `launchDir + '/output/mutFiles/*.mutfile'`

Comment: @Pallie Afraid not, I can see them getting created in my tests in the directory